# No result defined for action com.ril.tc.action.LoginAction and result success

Tags: java, struts2

I am creating LoginAction in Struts2. i have created the LoginAction class and configured in struts.xml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="index">
            <result>jsp/index.jsp</result>
      </action>   

      <action name="login"
            class="com.ril.tc.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">jsp/account/login.jsp</result>
        </action> 
   </package>
</struts>
```

Action class is as follows

```
package com.ril.tc.action;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import com.ril.tc.common.*;
import com.ril.tc.service.LoginService;

public class LoginAction extends BaseAction{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2112196951962991452L;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    public String execute() {       

        if (this.username.equals("admin") && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
            loginService.getUserList();
            return "success";
        } else {
            addActionError(getText("error.login"));
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

But when i executes the loginAction i receives below error.

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (CommonsLogger.java:38) - Could not find action or result
/TransConnect/login.action
No result defined for action com.ril.tc.action.LoginAction and result success
```

I am not getting what is the problem. i have mentioned the reult "success" and respective action.

Comment: can  you show you action class?

Comment: i have added action class.

Comment: what you URL you are hitting when you getting this error?

Comment: when i try to logged in..  my main page is /TransConnect/index. there will be ligin form. after hitting submit i am getting this error.

Comment: this is because `TransConnect` is your namespace,, either add a namespace `TransConnect` in your action mapping file or you can add action URL as  `<action name="TransConnect/login">`

Comment: The main problem is the **typo** , but take a look at the namespace config as @UmeshAwasthi suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 - HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757947/struts2-http-status-404-no-result-defined-for-action)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
<action name="login" class="com.ril.tc.account.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">jsp/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">jsp/account/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Your error:

> No result defined for action `com.ril.tc.action.LoginAction` and result success

Put them one below the other:

> com.ril.tc.**account**.LoginAction
>   com.ril.tc.**action**.LoginAction

:)

> "**Could not find action** or result"

It can't find the Action, not the result. Change the package or change struts config to make it works...

Comment: thanks @Andrea Ligios. by mystically i changed the struts.xml. even when i change to com.ril.tc.action.LoginAction i gets same error, in fact initially i had added LoginAction in account pkg. that time it was working fine. but when i changed to  action pkg it started giving error. finally i changed the action name from login to userLogin. now its working fine.